# Why is Stack Overflow deleting even well-received questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

My question is inspired by this question: [Deleted question audit 2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378437/3834).

So we can see what are the well-received questions (defined by either having high number of upvotes or many views) that are deleted, rightly or wrongly.

Stack Overflow's goal is to [build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and I don't see how we can achieve this goal by deleting questions and answers that are proven to be useful to programmers.

If you feel that the question no longer belongs on the site, you can always close it, instead of deleting it. Deleting it results in net information loss.

Since those deleted questions are still accessible by users with reputation >10k, obviously Stack Overflow are not deleting them in order to save some bandwidth or disk space.

So why is Stack Overflow *even* deleting well-received questions?

Some say that close is a temporary state that will eventually lead to either reopening or deletion. No middle ground. In that case, we still don't have to delete any questions, we can just put a historical lock on them.

Won't that be more appropriate?

Comment: Because being well received and being good are different. [Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378528/1394393). **Do not** make the mistake of thinking voting is a good measure of quality [the way SO did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302970/216712).

Comment: @Stijn, if having a bug in script is the _only_ reason for question deletion, then the mods should *immediately* restore well-received questions, without even asking for justification to do it on meta.

Comment: Popularity alone doesn't determine quality or fitness for the site.

Comment: Well-received, yes. High quality, not exactly. There's a difference between upvoting because "me too haha I love this programmer joke" and upvoting because it's a thought-provoking question.

Comment: @Graviton my mistake, not all those questions were deleted by the script bug.

Comment: @jpmc26 being well received means that it is being helpful to programmers, which is the goal of SO. Plus, being "good" or not is purely subjective. And it is not SO's goal-- to have good questions

Comment: No, it means it was popular. Entertaining. Liked. That is not the same thing. Also, **no**, SO's goal is to have *good answers*. Good questions are a means to an end.

Comment: That part you quoted from the tour is so terribly wrong and it should be changed. *"With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming."* It's not at all the goal of SO to answer every question about programming.

Comment: @Stijn It wasn't, but SO has changed. Quality no longer really matters to the staff. Their mission is now attract as many people as possible and make them happy, much to the detriment of the site.

Comment: @jpmc26 true, but before that they unwittingly created an army of us who will do whatever we can to stop that happening. The goal hasn’t changed, in my head at least. Viva la resistance or something...

Comment: @Clive Impossible not to upvote something that includes _"vive la résistance!"_.

Comment: @Clive The fact we feel like a resistance movement just makes me depressed.

Comment: @jpmc26, the problem is real and deeper that that. As a new user I already gave up on a lot of tag because of it's natural inclinaison to massivly upvote simple question. Json + c# is the most recent exemple I can give where chaging a json property name will give an other upvoted question. I'm not ready for this war so please veteran fight for us a little bit more don't give up. We are not ready for review vietnam.

Comment: @xdtTransform There's not much we *can* do to fight. If SO staff has their mind set, then we can't force them to reconsider.

Comment: the most downvotes you get, the more the thought provoking question you asked.

Answer (score 14):

*"Closed"* is not meant to be a permanent state, but a temporary state leading to either reopening (hopefully) or deletion. So "closing" questions permanently instead of deleting them is not a good solution.

Popularity, as measured with votes and view count, is not a good enough measure to judge a question quality and topicality. That's the reason we have methods to delete content that do not depend on those metrics.

Having off-topic questions remaining on the site [dilutes the catalog quality and the topicality message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory). Even more so if they are/were popular and have relative high scores, as they push forward the wrong message.

Stack Overflow means to be a *curated* catalog. In our case, a **huge** part of curation means deleting stuff.

Comment: In this case I will argue that it's better to have another meaning assigned to "Closed"-- not just a temporary state leading either to reopen or deletion, but also used to indicate that "the question no longer fits this site but preserved for all its historical and Google's worth".

Comment: That already exists. Is called "historical lock". But most of the time, if the content is off-topic here better it looks for a new home somewhere else (for the reasons that I already mentioned in my answer).

Comment: ... which brings to my point. Why is StackOverflow even deleting well-received questions? If we can't close it, then we can just "historical lock" it right?

Comment: I believe you are missing the point of the third paragraph of this answer.

Comment: I don't see how how can having locked questions ( and are clearly indicated as such) dilute the quality and the topicality message. In fact it will only serve to reinforce the commitment of this site to whatever qualities that you want in the questions

Comment: If you see a question that’s off topic, but locked, that doesn’t make you think _hmm, well they’ve done it, I’ll do it too_? I mean if not, great. But you are in the minority. For the most part it’s monkey see, monkey do. So we blind the monkey before it causes a problem.

Comment: Most of those questions are simply not good of fit with the site's purpose. **What's the argument for keeping them?** That they had votes at some point? SO shouldn't just preserve _anything_ with upvotes. If it's off-topic and do not belong the site, let's get rid of it.

Comment: Careful with your arguments here, people may think you are my sock puppet or something.

Comment: @yivi: "*What's the argument for keeping them?*" Because we **already had this discussion** years ago. We had a deal: highly upvoted, closed questions that were on-topic when asked can get historical locks. That was the deal. You don't get to renege on it now.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, the deal is questions that are *currently* of *massively* large value to the programming community as a whole can be kept around, even if off topic, and if needed to prevent deletion or reopening from a minority, a historical lock can be applied, if the community comes to the consensus that keeping it around is more valuable than the cost of having the off topic question.  Not all upvoted questions will quality for that, in fact, *very* few will.  Lots of even very highly upvotes questions won't qualify for that.